# am try to upload a 3gpp audio file in website? And there is any way to convert that 3gpp file into mp3 file?

Tags: jsp

am try to upload a 3gpp audio file in website? Is there a simple way to do that? And there is any way to convert that 3gpp file into mp3 file? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Well that depends on your server. If you have a linux machine you could use ffmpeg for conversion:

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -acodec mp3 -ar 22050 -f wav output.mp3
```

Just upload the file and trigger this command. Otherwise your server application itself would have to take care of that.

Comment: I have to do that in windows xp and windows 7.Tel me a way?

Comment: There are also Windows binaries available which should work:

http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z